# How to implement PSR-7?

Tags: php, psr-7

I've read about the PSR-7 but I simply couldn't understand how to implement it. Here's one example of something I did not understand:

The `withHeader` method would call a `header()` function? If so, how do I implement the `withoutHeader` method? If thats not the time and place to call `header()`, where (and when) is it?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: you can use some library that already implement that standard for you, i.e https://github.com/guzzle/psr7

Comment: and no, that's a HTTP message standard, the `header` function has [no use here](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/09/092556c9ea57329eefdbdd772f591c36f8d34758ee16379ae9a007c524c2afad.jpg).

Comment: Isn't the `header` function that appends a HTTP Header to the response? I'm completely in the dark here.

Comment: let's say that you implemented the `Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface` contract. how can I send it to the client?  with something like this: https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/App.php#L349

Comment: It uses the `header` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the code of symfony/http-foundation and it all became clear. If anyone has the same doubt I recommend seeing it.